# Gradle dependency cannot show in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I used maven a lot before, now, I want to investigate about gradle, but it seems gradle dont give me a good first impression.

When I config the repo, and build the project, intellij idea show me build successful, however, I cannot see the dependency from the project view, I have no idea why, I try to create several projects with almost same configuration, some of them will show dependency, some of them not, I have no idea why. Sometimes, the dependency will come out suddenly, and actually, I found gradle already download those dependnecy into the catch folder, but I have no idea why intellij cannot show it and use it.

Can someome show me how to fight with gradle and intellij?

Br,
Tim

Comment: I've been using IntelliJ with Gradle for almost 1.5 year and have never experienced such problems. What I can advise is to use `gradle wrapper` (also when importing project to IntelliJ).

Comment: Hej Opal, thanks for your reply, I use default gradle wrapper, I have no idea why it will looks like this, maybe something wrong with our nexus, if I choose maven central, everything is good, but if I choose our own repo, it will like this, but our repo works well at maven.

Comment: Have You configured the repo well? There are proxy issues as far as I know.

Comment: Proxy or authentication would be my guess. There is a section on this in userguide - http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories Of course your problem description is too vague to make sure someone can give you right advice.